# How to match a partial string to a range of possible values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `dataframes`:

`df1`:

| ZIP code | Other columns |
| --- | --- |
| 1011AA | ... |
| 1011AA | ... |
| 2316XH | ... |
| 5815NE | ... |

`df2`:

| starting value ZIP code range | last value ZIP code range | Province |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1200 | North-Holland |
| 1201 | 1500 | South-Holland |
| 1501 | 1570 | North-Holland |
| 1571 | 1600 | Den Haag |

I want to:

1. Get the first four digits of `df1["ZIP code"]`
2. Check if these four digits are present in any range in `df2["starting value ZIP code range"]` and `df["last value ZIP code range"]`
3. If there is a match, get `df2["Province"]` and add this value to a column in `df1`.

The difficulty is that I need to compare this to a range of values and I can only use the first 4 digits of the string. Most examples I found on stackoverflow compare based on a single value. The desired result is:

| ZIP code | New column |
| --- | --- |
| 1011AA | North-Holland |
| 1011AA | North-Holland |
| 2316XH | Haarlem |
| 5815NE | Utrecht |

Bonus points if you can do it using map. For example, `df1["New column"] = df1["ZIP code"].str[:4].map(... ? ...)`. However, if the `map` method is a bad idea please suggest a better method.

Comment: `df1['Province'] = pd.merge_asof(df1.assign(key=df1['ZIP code'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)), df2, left_on='key', right_on='starting value ZIP code range').query('key <= \`last value ZIP code range\`')['Province']`

Comment: The query does not look correct. Notice that the the province is not unique in df2. That is, the ranges are split.

Comment: It shouldn't matter. Let me provide a full answer and then you can test it and give me a counter example if needed

Comment: Please check the answer below and report any incorrect behavior with a reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your ranges are non-overlapping, you can use a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) on the starting boundary and filter its output (for example with [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)) to ensure it's within the ending boundary:

```
df1['Province'] = (
 pd.merge_asof(df1.assign(key=df1['ZIP code'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)), df2,
               left_on='key', right_on='starting value ZIP code range')
   .query('key <= `last value ZIP code range`')['Province']
)
```

Output:

```
  ZIP code Other columns       Province
0   1011AA           ...  North-Holland
1   1011AA           ...  North-Holland
2   2316XH           ...            NaN
3   5815NE           ...            NaN
```

##### other example

Let's add one more entry to `df2`:

```
# df2
   starting value ZIP code range  last value ZIP code range       Province
0                           1000                       1200  North-Holland
1                           1201                       1500  South-Holland
2                           1501                       1570  North-Holland
3                           1571                       1600       Den Haag
4                           5000                       6000        Utrecht


# output
  ZIP code Other columns       Province
0   1011AA           ...  North-Holland
1   1011AA           ...  North-Holland
2   2316XH           ...            NaN
3   5815NE           ...        Utrecht
```

Ensuring the boundaries in `df2` are numeric:

```
df2[['starting value ZIP code range', 'last value ZIP code range']] = \
df2[['starting value ZIP code range', 'last value ZIP code range']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: I get the following error: `Incompatible merge dtype, dtype('O') and dtype('int32'), both sides must have numeric dtype`

Comment: Ensure that the start/last columns in `df2` are numeric. See the update

Comment: Almost there, the current error is that we are comparing int32 and int64: `incompatible merge keys [0] dtype('int32') and dtype('int64'), must be the same type`. Can I adjust the `.astype(int)`?

Comment: I solved it by using .astype(np.int64)

Comment: Could you maybe explain why it is sufficient to only compare the `key` to the last value? I can see that we merge on the starting value, but I am still a little but puzzled

Comment: the `merge_asof` ensures that the match is ≥ the start, the `query` ensures than the match is <= the end. Because you have non-overlapping ranges, the `merge_asof` either puts the value in the correct range or overshoots in a non-existing one (which is then removed by the `query`)

Comment: So I tried to apply this example to my entire data set and got the following error: `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'`. Could this be caused a NaN values?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? You might want to `dropna` on `df2`.

Comment: I cannot share the data. I do not mind skipping NaN values, but I do not want to drop them from my data set. Does dropna only skip the NaN values or does it remove them entirely from my data set?

Comment: `dropna` doesn't mutate the original dataframe. If the NaNs are in `df2`, use `df2.dropna()` in the `merge_asof`